# Draw randomly from array without laying back

Tags: javascript

I would like to draw from an array randomly without having the drawn value in my initial array. So basically after each iteration the array shrinks um 1 value.

I have implemented the random draw part. However I struggle with the "laying back part".

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Company2',
    symbol: 'C2',
  },
  {
    name: 'Company3',
    symbol: 'C3',
  },
  {
    name: 'Company4',
    symbol: 'C4',
  },
]

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const value = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  console.log(`${i} draw: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`)
}
```

Any suggestions how to implement the `without laying back` part.

Comment: So draw a random item and *remove* it from the array? I'm not sure I understand the "laying back" portion.

Comment: @TylerRoper Exactly!

Comment: Consider using `arr.splice(...)[0]`, which will remove and return your value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Javascript's Splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) is a great function to achieve this.

Since you've already done the "random" part, we just need to extract the element from the array, instead of just printing it.

We can use `splice` to say: `companies.splice(randomPosition, 1)[0]`, which is basically:

- Remove one element after `randomPosition` from `companies`.
- This will return an `array with removed elements`, so we use `[0]` to get the first one from `splice` return.

This would result on something like this:

```js
const companies = [
  { name: 'Company 1', symbol: 'C1' },
  { name: 'Company 2', symbol: 'C2' },
  { name: 'Company 3', symbol: 'C3' },
  { name: 'Company 4', symbol: 'C4' },
]

while (companies.length > 0) {
  const randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * companies.length)
  const removedElement = companies.splice(randomPosition, 1)[0]
  
  console.log(removedElement)
}

console.log('companies is empty: ', companies)
```

PS: It's a bad practice to modify an `array` inside a `for` that is evaluating its `length` each iteration, so I changed it for a simplified loop.

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to add the `.splice()` method to remove the item from your array. You also should not re-evaluate the array length in your loop because you are removing items from it, so that number will decrease and end your loop earlier than you though.

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Company2',
    symbol: 'C2',
  },
  {
    name: 'Company3',
    symbol: 'C3',
  },
  {
    name: 'Company4',
    symbol: 'C4',
  },
]

for (let i = 0, iLength = arr.length; i < iLength ; i++) {

  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
  console.log(`${i} draw: ${JSON.stringify(arr.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0])}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the original array to be mutated you can use `.splice()`.

`.splice()` takes two parameters:

1. Element index (Required)
2. How many elements should be removed (Optional). If this parameter is not set then all items from that index will be removed

You'll need to keep the original length of the array since we will be mutating the original array.

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Company2',
    symbol: 'C2',
  },
  {
    name: 'Company3',
    symbol: 'C3',
  },
  {
    name: 'Company4',
    symbol: 'C4',
  },
];

const arrLength = arr.length;

for (let i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  const value = arr[index];
  console.log(`${i} draw: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`)
  arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The other answers here involving splice will work, but for efficiency and ease of coding, might I suggest a different approach? What if, instead of choosing random indexes from a sorted array, you shuffle the array and then just pop off the top, like a shuffled deck of cards? You can shuffle the array by "sorting" it with a comparator function that just randomly returns 1 or -1.

```
arr.sort(() => Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 1 : -1);
while (arr.length > 0) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.pop()));
}
```